# Match with negative lookahead postgreSQL redshift POSIX regex

Tags: regex, postgresql, posix, amazon-redshift

I want to match the first line and not the others:

```
http://example.com/shop/some-section/thing
http://example.com/shop/b/thing
http://example.com/shop/product/thing
```

I am trying regular expressions like this with no luck:

```
/shop/[^(b/)(product/)].*$
```

I'm looking for a solution that specifically matches strings without /b/ or /product/ in this part of the URL. The `.*` part at the end of my regex is just a placeholder, I will be matching other characters here in the actual code.

Comment: Have found an alternate method by merging two regex queries: `select (url ~ '/shop/.*$') and (url !~ '/shop/(b|product)/') as url from my.table`

Comment: The pattern looks good. What does it mean *with no luck*?

Comment: @klin I mean it does not work. [Here is some related documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html) for those unfamiliar with redshift

Comment: It doesn't work because doesn't work. Thanks for clarification. [I think it works well](http://rextester.com/UZECTO7042).

Comment: @klin appreciate the help, it looks my code is not working then for some other reason. my mistake. it's good to know that my original syntax should be working

Answer (score 1):

If your case is specific enough you could use [SPLIT_PART](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html):

```
select split_part('http://example.com/shop/some-section/thing', '/', 5) not in ('b', 'product');
     ?column?
    ----------
     t

select split_part('http://example.com/shop/b/thing', '/', 5) not in ('b', 'product');
     ?column?
    ----------
     f

select split_part('http://example.com/shop/product/thing', '/', 5) not in ('b', 'product');
     ?column?
    ----------
     f
```